# Populate dict using reduce() instead of loop

Tags: python, reduce

Edit: I've updated my question to clarify my goal.

Is there a way to speed-up this code by using reduce() or some other fast method rather than the *for* loop?
I looked at many similar questions but I did not find an answer.

```
old_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
keys = ['a', 'c', 'd']
new_dict = {}
for key in keys:
    new_dict[key] = old_dict.get(key)
print(new_dict)

# prints:
# {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': None}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not set on using `reduce`, you can chain a few built in functions together which should be very efficient.

```
new_dict = dict(zip(keys, map(old_dict.get, keys)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how about to use `functools.reduce`.

```
import functools
old_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
keys = ['a', 'c', 'd']
res = functools.reduce(lambda d,v: {**d, **{v : old_dict.get(v, None)}}, keys, {})
print(res)
```

---

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using @Peter 's answer. But here's an option using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```
from functools import reduce

old_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
keys = ['a', 'c', 'd']

def func(dct, key, old_dict=old_dict):
    dct[key] = old_dict.get(key)
    return dct

new_dict = reduce(func, keys, {})
print(new_dict)
```